# Applying Hankel transform for axisymmetric internal heat source

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, laplacian

I am trying to find the solution of $ \nabla^2U = U_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}U_r+U_{zz}=0$, where $0\leq r <\infty$, and $z>0$. The boundary conditions are given by $U(r,0)=A$ (A is constant), for $0\leq r <a$, and  $U(r,0)=0$ , for $r >a$.

Let $H(U(r,z)) = u(\alpha,z)$, $H(f(r)) = f(\alpha)$, then we have
$$
f(\alpha) = -\alpha^2u+u_{zz}=0
$$
Am I on the right track? I'm not exactly sure what to do next. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you know separation of variables? Have you solved similar problems in rectangular co-ordinates?

Comment: @Sal Thanks for the comment! I know the separation of variables, but haven't solved any problems like this.

Comment: Have a look at eg [section 3.4 in these](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/dbs26/1BMethods/Laplace.pdf) notes. It's quite a bit to ask for one question so I'd suggest trying it and asking about specific places you're stuck. In brief: let $U(r,z)=R(r)Z(z)$ and then get two ODEs (for $R$ and $Z$) by substituting into your equation. The solutions to these will be trig functions for $Z$ and Bessel functions for $R$

Comment: @Sal Thanks so much! but I am required to solve the question from Hankel transformation

Comment: Oh! In that case, you are on the right track. Just solve the ordinary differential equation for $u$. After that you'll need to invert the Hankel transform

Comment: @Sal Thanks you!